# C# object creator

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In javascript, I often use something like this object creator

```
  var o = new Object(); // generic object
  var props = { color:"red",value:5 }; // hashtable
  for(var key in props) o[key] = props[key];
  alert(o.color); //red
```

Can it be written as C# method with this declaration?

```
  static void properties(out Object o, HashTable h) { ...
```

Is this some design pattern? Am I inventing wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var test = new { name = "Testobj", color = Colors.Aqua };
        MessageBox.Show(test.name);
```

It's called a anonymous Type, I think this is what you are searching for.

Comment: Yes, this is almost it! Is there any way how to extract all "members" of anonymous type? Since it is not enumerable, foreach cannot be used.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the Expando Object in C# 4.  That is about as close as you are going to get to a dynamic object in C# like you can get in JavaScript.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/BlogDetail.aspx?BlogId=2134

Answer (score 0):

Since c# is statically typed, you cannot achieve this..  closest possible is anonymous methods

```
Dictionary<string,int> dic=new Dictionary<string,int>();
            dic.Add("red", 5);
            dic.Add("black", 10);
            dic.Add("white", 1);
            object[] obj;
            foreach(var o in dic)
            {
                var sam= new { color = o.Key,value=o.Value };
                Console.WriteLine(sam.color);               

            }
```